# What operations are time consuming and how to avoid them?

Tags: c++, performance

I am fairly new to c++ and I want to learn how to optimize the speed of my programs. I am currently working on a program that computes the perfect numbers from 1 to 1.000.000. A perfect number is where the sum of its proper divisors is equal to the number itself. Eg. 28 is a perfect number because 1+2+4+7+14=28. Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int a = 1000000;

for(int i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int q; 

    // The biggest proper divisor is half the number itself
    if(i % 2 == 0) q = i/2;
    else q = (i+1)/2;


    for(int j = 1; j <= q; ++j)
    {
        if(i % j == 0) sum += j;
    }

    //Condition for perfect number
    if(sum == i) cout << i << " is a perfect number!" << endl;
}

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

What operations in this code are time consuming? How can I improve the speed of the program? In general, how do I learn about what operations that are time consuming and how to avoid them?

Comment: Have you profiled the code yet?

Comment: Micro optimization: you may use `q = (i+1)/2;` without the `if`.

Comment: You have no "operation" which is really time consuming. You programmed some kind of algorithm which is maybe not the fastest for your problem. Using a profiler is not very helpful I believe, because it will show you how long and often a code line is called. But there is no code block which can be optimized away by hand. For me it looks like a question for a better algorithm and not for a specific slow codeline.

Comment: Similar to [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), you may trade computation with memory.

Comment: @Klaus: I don't think that the OP is looking for an efficient algorithm; this is just an exercise in programming. A truly efficient solution for this case would be `cout << "6, 28, 496, 8128";`

Comment: @Yves: I believe `printf` is never the fastest way :-) I have no idea which is the basic task for the OP. If it is a tutorial question, yes, he simply has to use a profiler :-)

Comment: @Klaus: if the program has to ouput the results to the console, I doubt you can beat `cout << "6, 28, 496, 8128";` (Possibly `printf` can be slightly faster.)

Comment: I would think `i & 1` would be faster than `i % 2` and also `i >> 1` should be faster than `i / 2`.

Comment: @Galik: you are right; optimizing compilers know this trick and enforce it when they see that the argument is a power of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to really know what operations are time consuming and are limiting the execution speed of your program is to run the program through a profiler. This tool will tell you where each second of the execution time was spent (on a function call basis, usually).

To answer your question specifically: the most time in this program will be spent at this line:

```
system("pause");
```

because, aside from the fact that this is a horrible line of code you should get rid of, is actually user input, and as we all know, the thing between the chair and the screen is what slows things down.

Comment: "the thing between the chair and the screen"... damn!

Comment: No need of a profiler to see that all time in spent in `if(i % j == 0) sum += j;`

Answer (score 1):

You may trade of computation by memory consumption with the following:

```
const int max = 1000000;
std::vector<std::size_t> a(max);

for(std::size_t i = 1; i != a.size(); ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = 2 * i; j < a.size(); j += i) {
        a[j] += i;
    }
}
for (std::size_t i = 1; i != a.size(); ++i) {
    if(a[i] == i) {
        std::cout << i << " is a perfect number!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/IpZY9e)

Answer (score 0):

My rules of thumb:

- conditional branches (i.e. comparisons) are costly
- divisions are costly (as well as modulo %)
- prefer integer operations over floating-point

How to avoid them ?

Well, there is no simple answer. In many cases you just can't.

You avoid conditional branches by using branchless expressions, or improving the program logics.

You avoid divisions by using shifts or lookup-tables or rewriting expressions (when possible).

You avoid floating-point by simulating fixed-point.

In the given example, you have to focus on the body of the innermost loop. That's the line that is the most frequently executed (about 125000000000 times vs 1000000 for others). Unfortunately, there is a comparison and a division, which are hard to remove.

Optimizations of other parts of the code will have no measurable effect. In particular, don't worry about the `cout` statement: it will be called 4 times in total.

Comment: That's mostly depend on the hardware... If your processor has an FPU, floating point perform more or less like int, division and multiplication are essentially the same thing. If the processor has piping, branches are costly only if not predictable... etc. etc.

Comment: @Emilio: My rules do hold for a PC, but not only. Division is nowhere as fast as multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Branches:  `if`s, loops, function calls and `goto` are costly.  They tend to distract the processor from perform data transfers and math operations.

For example, you can eliminate the `if` statement:

```
q = (i + (i % 2)) / 2;  // This expression not simplified.
```

Research loop unrolling, although the compiler may perform this on higher optimization settings.

I/O operations are costly, especially using formatted I/O.
Try this:

```
if(sum == i)
{
  static const char text[] = " is a perfect number!\n";
  cout << i;
  cout.write(text, sizeof(text) - 1); // Output as raw data.
}
```

Division and modulo operations are costly.
If you can divide by a power of 2, you can convert the division into a shift right.
You may be able to avoid modulo operations by using binary AND.